# Choosing akka persistence db

Tags: akka, akka-persistence

The default database for Akka persistence is LevelDB, but I saw that there are plugins for Redis, MongoDB, and others.

1. What are the factors that I should take into account when choosing between them? In my use case, I want to use persistence for recovery after processes fail. The state of the actor is a big data structure with high throughput of write/read operations.
2. Another option is that the actor will use directly Redis persistence without any plugin for Akka persistence. Is this option less preferred?